# Logging all SQL executed in time period

Tags: sql-server, database-tuning

In MS SQL Server 2008, I would like to investigate and tune the queries that are being executed by an application in a limited time interval. Can I, e.g. from SQL Server Management Studio, generate a log of all SQL being executed and how long time each query took (and which parameters they were executed with)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929.aspx) for this purpose - from SSMS, go to Tools -> SQL Server Profiler.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the MS SQL Profiler to do this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181091.aspx